# Use same autocompletes on multiple language syntax on sublime text

Tags: css, macos, sass, sublimetext2

How do I get all autocompletes from one language syntax and bring them to another language on sublime text 2?

I'm working with SASS and I would like to have all CSS autocomplete on SCCS files syntax, is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Download -  [**Sass for TextMate/Sublime Text 2**](https://github.com/nathos/sass-textmate-bundle)

Install it via the Package manager

**Preferences** --> **Package Control** --> **Install Package**

Search for **Sass**, and it should be the first option in the list.

Comment: Yeah, but doing this i lost all the .scss highlight.. i would like to keep the highlight on scss files too

Comment: Thats the package im using to get SASS highlight, the only bad thing on this package is that the autocompletes are not so good as the css autocompletes...

Thats why i would like to take all CSS autocomplete and use the same in SASS files you know?

Thanks for the attention!